# Faker Gem creating fake picture not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, faker

Why am i not able to create a fake picture?

Picture is polymorphic to several things including the model proposal:

This is my faker data:

```
for n in 1..10 do
  picture = Picture.create!(
    picture: Faker::Avatar.image("my-own-slug"),
    imageable_type: 'Proposal',
    imageable_id: n)
end
```

The imageable type and imageable id get saved correctly I can verify via console. but my picture field remains nil

```
picture: nil
```

If just run `Faker::Avatar.image("my-own-slug")` in my console I get this:

```
"http://robohash.org/my-own-slug.png?size=300x300&set=set1"
```

which is what I am looking for. Why is it not working from my seed?

I am seeding alot of other data and it all is working well with Faker except images. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by saving an image to my root folder and just seeding it with its explicit url to my root folder:

```
for n in 1..10 do
  picture = Picture.create!(
    picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "Joan_Baez_Bob_Dylan_crop.jpg")),
    imageable_type: 'Proposal',
    imageable_id: n)
end
```

Comment: Since passing a file into the picture attribute works when passing a string (from Faker::Avatar.image) didn't, I'm guessing that the Picture model is using Paperclip (or some other file upload gem), and the picture setter expects to receive a file rather than a string.